# How to merge documents and decide on any change?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Let's say I'm merging two document's and some changes make conflicts and others do not.
How to "merge" and be able to decide about every single change?

Doc master

```
<h1>hello<h1>
<h2 class="user"> sranger <h2>
```

Doc my_branch

```
<h1>helloo<h1>
<h2 class="user"> sranger <h2>
    
<script>
  let user='Miki Mouse'
  console.log(user)
  $(".user").html(user)
</script>
```

This is what I expect after merging on branch master:

```
<h1>hello<h1>
<h2 class="user"> sranger <h2>
    
<script>
  let user='Miki Mouse'
  $(".user").html(user)
</script>
```

In this example it should ask me about conflict helloo - hello and if I accept every single line of the script so I could exclude console.log
I'm working on VSC if it's make difference

Comment: What's your question? "How to solve conflicts upon merge"?

Comment: How to accept or reject changes taht are not considered as conflict?

Comment: You could use `--no-commit` as an option for your merge, then review changes (for example with `git reset -p` to unstage what you don't want to be included). And eventually merge the result. But beware of [evil merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary/2.22.0#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefevilmergeaevilmerge)...